# Use Aspects in Spring to calculate method processing time

Tags: java, spring-mvc, aop, aspectj, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC web application which connects to an external web service for different operations. To calculate the service response times for web requests I have use aspectj to log around service calls. I can perfectly log the time taken to execute the web service method.

But I want to display these response times in the HTML view as well. I couldn't find a way to get this time value back to the views. Your ideas are much appreciated.

Here is how I log these times into a CSV file using sl4j.

```
@Around("execution(* backend.channel.ServiceWrapper.*(..))")
public Object logAroundServiceCall( ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint ) throws Throwable
{
    StopWatch sw = new StopWatch();
    sw.start();
    Object returnVal = null;
    try
    {
        returnVal = joinPoint.proceed();
    }
    catch ( Exception e )
    {
        LOGGER.error( e.getMessage(), e );
    }
    finally
    {
        sw.stop();
        SERVICE_TIME_LOGGER.info( "{},{}", joinPoint.getSignature().getName(), sw.getTotalTimeMillis() );
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There could be a lot of ways to do this, I'll give you two possibilities:

1. **The easier, but less elegant method**: you could use a `ThreadLocal` variable. The `ThreadLocal` variable is a per-thread storage method for storing arbitrary values. Your advice could store the list of your profiling results in a `ThreadLocal` and have code executing somewhere later in your request/response cycle which collects the data, clears the `ThreadLocal` and renders it in the UI.
2. **Just a little bit harder, but more elegant method**: imagine the collection of profiling data as an event producer and the data collector part of your UI renderer as a consumer of those events, rendering them later in the rendering phase when your service calls are all finished. You will only need to set up your aspect with the event system so it can publish events when they occur, and register your UI renderer to listen to those events. Use `AspectName.aspectOf()` to get the instance of a singleton aspect and use it as pretty much any POJO to set it up with your event system.